# Finding max and min on a disk

Tags: calculus, maximum-principle

The problem I'm having trouble with is this;

The temperature at all points in the disk $x^2 + y^2 {\leq} 1$ is given by $T = (x+y)e^{-x^2-y^2}$. Fine the minimum and maximum temperatures at the points of the disk.

So I know we can start at $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, which means $y$ or $x = 0$

I found the gradient to be ${\nabla}f(x,y) = ((x+y)(-2xe^{-x^2-y^2}) + (1+y)e^{-x^2-y^2}, (x+y)(-2ye^{-x^2-y^2}) + (1+x)(e^{-x^2-y^2}))$

Though I don't see how this could be much help.

Can someone guide me through this problem?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you would start assuming $x^2+y^2=1$ (which in fact is NOT where the extrema are.  Further, even if you assume that, how do you get $x=0$ or $y=0$?

Comment: If we know the max, then the min is clear, switch signs. For the max, using polars, for fixed $r$ it is at $x=y$, now maximize over $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to solve this is to find stationary points (or *critical points*) in the interior of the disk first, and afterwards look at the boundary of the disk by itself.

To find stationary points in the **interior**, solve the gradient equal to zero for $(x,y)$, and check if they're within the disk. That is, solve
$$\nabla T(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{dT}{dx}\\\frac{dT}{dy}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\end{bmatrix}. $$
The system is

$$ \nabla T(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} -e^{-x^2-y^2}(2x^2+2xy-1)\\-e^{-x^2-y^2}(2y^2+2xy-1)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
which implies
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2x^2+2xy-1\\2y^2+2xy-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\end{bmatrix} $$
and solving yields $(x,y) = \left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$ or $(x,y)=\left(-\frac12,-\frac12\right)$.

To check the **boundary**, you can parametrize it by

$$(x(t),y(t)) = (\cos t,\sin t) $$
where $t\in[0,2\pi)$. Again, find stationary points (with respect to $t$), by solving $$\frac{d}{dt}T(x(t),y(t))=0.$$

We have that
$$T(x(t),y(t)) = (\cos t +\sin t)e^{-(\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t)} = (\cos t +\sin t)e^{-1} $$
and hence its derivative
$$\frac{d}{dt}T(x(t),y(t)) = (-\sin t + \cos t)e^{-1} = 0$$
which implies
$$-\sin t + \cos t = 0 $$
which occurs when $t=\frac\pi 4+p\pi$ and $p\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since we're restricted to $t\in[0,2\pi)$, we only have the options $p=0$ or $p=1$, that is $t=\frac14\pi$ or $t =\frac54\pi$. We now have four candidates for maxima and minima namely
\begin{align}
(x,y)&=\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\\
(x,y)&=\left(-\frac12,-\frac12\right)\\
(x,y)&=\left(x\left(\frac14\pi\right),y\left(\frac14\pi\right)\right)=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
(x,y)&=\left(x\left(\frac54\pi\right),y\left(\frac54\pi\right)\right)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right).
\end{align}
Check $T$ in all these points and you know what minimum and maximum is.

Comment: As you aren't checking the Hessian, you may also want to appeal to the fact that this is a continuous function on a closed cont. compact domain, hence it has a max and min.

Answer (score 0):

$(f_x,f_y) = (0,0) \Rightarrow \begin{cases} -2x(x+y)+1+y = 0 \\ -2y(x+y) + 1 + x = 0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow (x-y)(2x+2y + 1) = 0$. From this you can find the critical points, and take it from there.

Comment: Did you just take the partial derivatives of both x and y and then just plug in $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: No, I factor $e^{-x^2-y^2}$ out since $e^{-x^2-y^2} \neq 0$.

Comment: Do you just leave it aside because it will cancel to 1 or... what?

Comment: Check your partials.  These look wrong, you have an extra $x$ or $y$ at the end of each.  You should get $(x, y) = \pm (\frac12, \frac12)$ for the critical points, here you get something else.